# How to understand the branch of a complex function is not defined at a point?

Tags: complex-analysis

I saw an exercise which asks to solve the integral $\int_{-1}^1 z^idz$, where $z^i = \exp(iLog(z))$ $(|z|>0, -\pi <Arg(z)<\pi)$. The solution says an antiderivative of this branch cannot be used since the branch is not even defined at $z=-1$. Then they replace the integrand by the branch $$z^i = \exp(i\log z)$$ where $|1+iz|>0, -\pi/2 <Arg(z)<3\pi/2)$

- Question: what does it mean by the branch being not defined at $z=-1$? Does it mean that $Log(z)$ is not differentiable at $z=-1$? I know the branch cut of $Log(z)$ is the non-positive real axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here they decided to use the branch which is the non negative real axis. And yes, if you choose this branch then you can't define logarithm on the negative real axis in a continuous way. In the points which are just above $-1$ (by above I mean the points near $-1$ which are in the top half of the complex plane) the argument is very close to $\pi$, at the points which are just below $-1$ the argument is very close to $-\pi$. So no chance to define $Log(-1)$ in a continuous way. And if a function is not continuous at a point then of course it can't be differentiable there.

Comment: Under which condition, do we say the branch is not defined at $z=-1$?

Comment: Exactly the condition that I wrote-if we can't define it in a continuous way. If we choose the branch $-\pi<arg(z)<\pi$ then the domain of the branch is $\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0]$. If the branch is $0<arg(z)<2\pi$ then the domain is $\mathbb{C}\setminus [0,\infty)$. These are the two most common branches, though there are infinitely many.